# Django : django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, django

Stack trace:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f58375ac9b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 229, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 168, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 191, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 204, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show your database settings here and put your error log in a better format.

I guess you're using SQLite, right? If so please check your data file path:
- Is it correct? Should be full-path.
- Does your app has right permissions (read/write) on it and its parent directories
- Make sure its parent directories created.